# "IPOPT" Provided package HSL is not working or does not contain MA27

Tags: c++, windows, ipopt

I am trying to install IPOPT. I am following the installation steps from [here](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html). I got the official HSL file (academic). I was able to `./configure` and `make` and `make install` it. I made sure to rename the folder to "coinhsl" as is required by [this](https://github.com/coin-or-tools/ThirdParty-HSL) repo.

When I try to install Ipopt I keep getting this error

```
checking for LAPACK... yes: generic library (-llapack -lblas)
checking for package ASL... yes
checking for package Mumps... yes
checking for MPI_Initialized... no
checking for package HSL... yes
checking for function ma27ad_ in -lcoinhsl   ... no
checking for function ma27ad in -lcoinhsl   ... no
checking for function MA27AD_ in -lcoinhsl   ... no
checking for function MA27AD in -lcoinhsl   ... no
checking for function ma27ad__ in -lcoinhsl   ... no
checking for function ma27ad_ in -lcoinhsl   ... no
checking for function MA27AD__ in -lcoinhsl   ... no
checking for function MA27AD_ in -lcoinhsl   ... no
configure: error: Provided package HSL is not working or does not contain MA27. See config.log for details on failed checks.
```

I tried to follow the solutions given [here](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/issues/434) but I am unable to resolve the error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit 1:

@RichardCritten This is something i found on investigating the logs

```
configure:24545: checking for function MA27AD_ in -lcoinhsl   
configure:24570: gcc -o conftest.exe -O2 -DNDEBUG    conftest.c -lcoinhsl    >&5
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcoinhsl: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Although, I still don't understand, why "-lcoinhsl" isn't created.

Comment: _"... See config.log for details..."_ what's in here ?

Comment: I had the same issue. What I did is run first the compilation for the HSL, (configure make make install), then I ran the configure make install for the third-party-hsl github repo (https://github.com/coin-or-tools/ThirdParty-HSL) and only then Ipopt finds the libraries. 
You if you just Configure/make/inst. the coinhsl it is not enough for it to find it.

Comment: The message
```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcoinhsl: No such file or directory
```
says that the linker called by `configure` from Ipopt could not find the coinhsl library. This lib should have been build by `ThirdParty-HSL` and installed somewhere by `make install`, but now there is a problem to locate it.

Have a look for line `Libs:` in the `coinhsl.pc` file that was installed when you build `ThirdParty-HSL`. It should have contained a `-L` argument with the path to the coinhsl lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar  issue, but **[offcial documentation](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html)** it is clearly say how to do it,

Steps:

1. Go to http://hsl.rl.ac.uk/ipopt and get **Coin-HSL sources archive**
2. git clone https://github.com/coin-or-tools/ThirdParty-HSL.git
3. cd ThirdParty-HSL
4. Now **unpack** the **Coin-HSL sources archive**, **move** and **rename** the resulting directory so that it becomes **ThirdParty-HSL/coinhsl**
5. cd ThirdParty-HSL

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
6. Then, follow the rest of the instructions provided in the **[offcial documentation](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html)**